# ReactJS Json-loader working in app but not storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently converting an application to typescript. My npm start is working without any problem but when I try to run [react-storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/react-storybook) I have this error

```
ERROR in ./src/conf.json
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.module.exports (/node_modules/json-loader/index.js:7:48)
 @ ./srcReact/actions/ApiActions.js 4:16-46
```

Both are using the same loaders in webpack.config.js

```
loaders: [
            {
                exclude: [
                    /\.html$/,
                    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    /\.css$/,
                    /\.json$/,
                    /\.svg$/
                ],
                loader: 'url-loader',
                query: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, '../') ],
                exclude: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundles') ],
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                    plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
                    cacheDirectory:true
                },
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, '../') ],
                exclude: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundles') ],
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: "svg-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            }
        ]
```

I also have a json.d.ts for the json

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

After some tests it looks like the storybook is not able to load my json defition (json.d.ts).

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a ts-loader in your webpack config. How did you configure typescript with storybook? I have one project written in Typescript, integrated with storybook and it works without problems.

Comment: Humm, i'll try that. But actually if I don't load any JSON in the storybook everything is working without a ts-loader. Maybe it'll change something. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working by changing my module declaration to

```
declare module "!json!*" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Adding the first ! removed the confusion between the json-loader and the typescript module. Got inspired by this github issue https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader/issues/13